# Are Positive Polynomials dense on positive continuos functions?

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, functional-analysis, polynomials, metric-spaces

By the Wiestrass theorem, it is known that polynomials are dense on the set of continuous functions with respect to the distance induced by the uniform norm
$$
\forall f \in C^0([0, 1], \mathbb{R}) \ \ \|f\|_{\infty} = \sup_{t\in [0,1]} |f(t)|
$$
However, is the set of positive polynomial dense on the set of positive continuous functions with respect to the uniform norm?

Comment: $\sqrt f$ is a  continuous function. If $p$ approximates $\sqrt f$ uniformly then $p^{2}$ approximates $f$ uniformly.

Comment: You can answer that yourself. Choose $\epsilon>0$ and add ${ 1 \over 2} \epsilon$ to $f$. Can you approximate this function by a suitable polynomial so that the polynomial is positive?

Comment: What is your definition of "positive?" Do you mean $>0$ or $\ge 0$?

Comment: @copper.hat I not able to answer my self. Seems simple, but I cannot get with the answer.

Comment: @RafaelRojas Choose $\epsilon>0$ and some function $f \ge 0$. Let $f' = f+{1 \over 2} \epsilon$, so $f' \ge {1 \over 2} \epsilon$ everywhere. Now find a polynomial $p$ such that $\|f'-p\|_\infty < {1 \over 4} \epsilon$, then you have $\|f-p\|_\infty < {3 \over 4} \epsilon$ (triangle inequality) and $p \ge {1 \over 4} \epsilon$ (triangle inequality again). It might help to draw a little picture to see what is going on here.